# How to change actionbar title color in Xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-actionbar, xamarin.android

How do I change my actionbar title color in Xamarin android programmatically?
I tried a lot of things on the internet, but I just can't find a way to do it.

I don't want to switch to toolbar, because I don't know the code for it, I also dont know if it's possible to make a toolbar look like exactly the same as the actionbar in the code below.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Graphics;

namespace actionbarTitleColor
{
    [Activity(Label = "myActivity")]
    public class myActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Rapsolie);
            ActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.ParseColor("#00b8ff"));
            ActionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item) {

            switch (item.ItemId) {
                case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                    Finish();
                    return true;

                default:
                    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straight-forward method is that customizing a style for your `ActionBar`, for example like this:

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#f08080</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Then apply this style in your page like this:

```
[Activity(Label = "YOURPACKAGENAME", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme")]
```

There are many discussions talking about customizing the style of `ActionBar`, you may search for them.

> I don't want to switch to toolbar, because I don't know the code for it, I also dont know if it's possible to make a toolbar look like exactly the same as the actionbar in the code below.

I personally think use `Toolbar` is easier for custom layout, but it is available since android 5.0, for the part how to code for `Toolbar`, you may refer to [Toolbar](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/toolbar/).